# Capture error message of isql in python subprocess method

Tags: python, subprocess, isql

I am executing isql command using python subprocess.I am using below code to capture output and error message.

```
command = "./isql -S "+mdbserver+" -U "+muserid+" -P "+mpassword+" -D "+mdatabase+" -s '"+self.Delimiter+"' -w 99999 <<EOF\nSET NOCOUNT ON\n"+Query+"\ngo\nEOF"
output, err = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,cwd=sybase_bin)
```

output and error of my isql command is coming in output variable. How to capture error message of isql in err variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `stderr` argument:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True,
    cwd=sybase_bin
)
```

Then:

```
output, error = proc.communicate()
```

See [the docs for more details](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Comment: I am still getting error in output variable. I need to capture error in error variable

Comment: It might be that the errors are being reported through STDOUT in that case. You might need to check the docs and command line switches for isql.

Comment: I have added --retserverror in my -isql command. now I am getting error code in error variable.